# Read csv dataset above 5gb

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read the dataset which has size above 5gb. The dataset I downloaded it from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/riiid-test-answer-prediction/data?select=train.csv).

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/train.csv",
                       low_memory=False,
                       nrows=10**5,
                       dtype={'row_id': 'int64', 'timestamp': 'int64', 'user_id': 'int32', 'content_id': 'int16',
                              'content_type_id': 'int8','task_container_id': 'int16', 'user_answer': 'int8',
                              'answered_correctly': 'int8', 'prior_question_elapsed_time': 'float32',
                              'prior_question_had_explanation': 'boolean'},
                       parse_dates=["timestamp"],
                       date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
```

I tried the above code, I specified the dtypes and then convert all the timestamp to datetime but I get error such as:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in converter(*date_cols)
   3358                 result = tools.to_datetime(
-> 3359                     date_parser(*date_cols), errors="ignore", cache=cache_dates
   3360                 )

<ipython-input-82-2cac40069ffd> in <lambda>(x)
      8                        parse_dates=["timestamp"],
----> 9                        date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
     10 questions_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/questions.csv")

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in converter(*date_cols)
   3367                         parsing.try_parse_dates(
-> 3368                             parsing.concat_date_cols(date_cols),
   3369                             parser=date_parser,

pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.concat_date_cols()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.convert_to_unicode()

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-2cac40069ffd> in <module>
      7                               'prior_question_had_explanation': 'boolean'},
      8                        parse_dates=["timestamp"],
----> 9                        date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
     10 questions_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/questions.csv")
     11 lectures_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/lectures.csv")

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    456 
    457     try:
--> 458         data = parser.read(nrows)
    459     finally:
    460         parser.close()

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1194     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1195         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1196         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1197 
   1198         # May alter columns / col_dict

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2228             data = {k: v for k, (i, v) in zip(names, data)}
   2229 
-> 2230             names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
   2231             index, names = self._make_index(data, alldata, names)
   2232 

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _do_date_conversions(self, names, data)
   1968                 self.index_names,
   1969                 names,
-> 1970                 keep_date_col=self.keep_date_col,
   1971             )
   1972 

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _process_date_conversion(data_dict, converter, parse_spec, index_col, index_names, columns, keep_date_col)
   3411                 if _isindex(colspec):
   3412                     continue
-> 3413                 data_dict[colspec] = converter(data_dict[colspec])
   3414             else:
   3415                 new_name, col, old_names = _try_convert_dates(

c:\users\public\pycharmprojects\codility_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in converter(*date_cols)
   3373                     )
   3374                 except Exception:
-> 3375                     return generic_parser(date_parser, *date_cols)
   3376 
   3377     return converter

c:\users\public(parse_func, *cols)
     36     for i in range(N):
     37         args = [c[i] for c in cols]
---> 38         results[i] = parse_func(*args)
     39 
     40     return results

<ipython-input-82-2cac40069ffd> in <lambda>(x)
      7                               'prior_question_had_explanation': 'boolean'},
      8                        parse_dates=["timestamp"],
----> 9                        date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
     10 questions_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/questions.csv")
     11 lectures_df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}/lectures.csv")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

.shape
train_df.shape
```

I understand the error is because i need to convert too many rows from timestamp to datetime, but I think I saw there was a method to do so and I forgotten about it. Could someone please assist? Thank you.

Comment: Try using [dask.dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) it is meant for large datasets that do not fit into your memory.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your problem, but could you read it and then make the transformation? For some reason, it is not recognising that the `lambda` function you passed is a function.

Comment: I dont understand why too, I tried to change the nrows=10000 and it worked but when I used more than 100000 then it failed. I even make transformation to the lambda function.

Comment: Could anyone assist with this question if possible?